# Joing Ads Data in Ads Data Hub with GA360 Data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-ads-data-hub

I need to find a way how to (SQL)-join my GA360 tables in BigQuery(BQ) with data within AdsDataHub(ADH).

I already know how to query tables from BQ within ADH:

```
SELECT *
FROM 'projectname.table_name'
```

But I cant find any resources on what matching key to use in the Join statement

```
 SELECT
   *
 FROM
   adh.*** AS adh_data       
   adh_data LEFT JOIN ???
   ON ga360.??? = ???
```

I read through this https://developers.google.com/ads-data-hub/guides/join-your-data
But it's not really clear to me what to get/use from it and I couldn't find any information on this topic anywhere.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ADH doesn't currently allow for querying across google analytics data sets (which would already be in ADHs "clean room" if they wanted you to be able to make such queries...)

Your best option might be to A: make sure that you're capturing 1st party IDs in your google analytics implementation and B: ensuring those IDs are also captured in your CRM platforms as they interact with your properties (assumption being your CRM can capture, along with that ID, any Google Analytics related data you may find useful, though it won't be log level I don't think...)

From there, with "onboarding" of sorts, you may be able to eventually drop your CRM data into ADH queryable tables which can be joined (per the link you shared, "join your data") and then well... you're at google's behest for the most part, but I think that's the path you're looking for...

PS: Google may have some solutions with guides that include some useful example queries regarding join keys across CM/DV/GoogleAds tables, and they may be high quality, but they may not be EXACTLY what you're looking for... It's entirely possible they are not publicly available though...